# VBA code to go to the first non populated row

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write code to have a button go to the first non blank cell.

The problem is that he screen is split & **the button is located on the lower half of the split**.

When I run the following code :`Application.Goto Sheet1.Range("A1"), True`

it brings to the first non populated row on the top, to the **bottom half of the split**.

The bottom half of the split must stay stationary. Does any team member have any thoughts how I can have it do that in the top half of the split?

Comment: Your code only goes to A1, not the first non-populated row.  As for the split screen thing, add this line above your existing line of code to force the code to use the top of the split: `ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Activate`

Comment: You are correct. It was just easier coding. That little piece of code, did the trick. Thank you.